# Freeing a jagged array in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

float **div(float **A, float **B, int row, int column) {
  float **D;
  D = new float *[row];
  // D= ( float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * row);
  for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    D[x] = new float[column];
    // D[x] = (float (*))malloc(sizeof(float) * column);
    for (int y = 0; y < column; y++) {
      D[x][y] = (A[x][y] / B[x][y]);
    }
  }

  return D;
}

int main() {
  int x = 0, y = 0, row = 20, column = 5;
  float **N;
  // N =(float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * row);
  N = new float *[row];
  for (x = 0; x < row; x++) {
    N[x] = new float[column];
    // N[x]=(float*)malloc(row*column*sizeof(float));
    for (y = 0; y < (column); y++) {
      N[x][y] = 1;
    }
  }

  N = div(N, N, row, column);
  cout << "Displaying  N  ..." << endl;
  for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
      cout << N[x][y] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    delete[] N[x];
  }
  delete[] N;
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to free the all the memory, but it is freed the memory which I declared in main, but the function `div` also occupying the same memory of size input array N and it is not freed. Is there any way to delete the memory which is occupied the function.

Comment: Don't overwrite `N` with a new value, use a different variable for the return value.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Why not using `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` (or `std::array<20, std::array<4, float>>`)?

Comment: Ouch.  Jarod, :vector<vector> is an extremely disgusting way to do a multidimensional away.  It's actually quite horrific.  No, it's worse than horrific.  I actually can't find the words...  OP should use boost::multiarray or similar.  Something designed to allocate a single blob of memory and give him an accessor.  It doesn't have to be an operator, although that's always nice.

Comment: @Robinson At least `std::unique_ptr<std::array<20, std::array<4, float>>>` should work well, if there's no need to have the dimensions determined at runtime.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: copy/paste is evil: I did a mistake in the order ~~`array<N, T>`~~ instead of correct `std::array<T, N>` ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 anyway, should be a viable way under the conditions I've mentioned. I'v just added `unique_ptr` to reveal from stack size restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at here, my example of new and delete a `int[m][n]`, I hope this can help you:

```
int main()
{
    //a[m][n]
    const int m = 5, n=6;
    int **p = new int*[m];
    for(int i=0; i<m; ++i)
        p[i] = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<m; ++i)
        delete[] p[i];  //delete array
    delete[] p;
    p = nullptr;

}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but i am asking about how to free the heap memory

Comment: @CharanKumar， the `new` is used for allocating the heap memory, the `delete` is used for freeing the heap memory! Maybe you should learn the `c++ primer` firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::array` would remove memory management:

```
template <std::size_t ROW, std::size_t COL>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<float, COL>, ROW>;

template <std::size_t ROW, std::size_t COL>
Matrix<ROW, COL> div(const Matrix<ROW, COL>& A, const Matrix<ROW, COL>& B)
{
    Matrix<ROW, COL> res;
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x != ROW; ++x) {
       for (std::size_t y = 0; y != COL; ++y) {
           res[x][y] = (A[x][y]/B[x][y]);
       }
    }
    return res;
} 

template <std::size_t ROW, std::size_t COL>
void display(const Matrix<ROW, COL>& m)
{
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x != ROW; ++x) {
       for (std::size_t y = 0; y != COL; ++y) {
           std::cout << m[x][y] << " ";
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<20, 5> N;
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x != 20; ++x) {
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y != 5; ++y) {
            N[x][y] = 1;
        }
    }
    N = div(N, N);
    std::cout << "Displaying  N  ..." << std::endl;
    display(N);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mrs3L6)

Comment: Thanks for swift response, but how to free the memory

Comment: @CharanKumar: With your prototype, you cannot do `N = div(N, N, row, column);` without memleak. You have to do `float **M = div(N, N, row, column);` and then delete both `M` and `N` (with your loop).